# mysqli insert_id not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Can someone take a look at this and tell me why it's not working. This is part of a class that I'm working on. The insert query works fine and if I call $char->db->insert_id; from outside the class it works ($char being the class)

```
function createChar($charName, $charRace, $charClass) {
    //put userId, charName and charRace into database
    $sql="insert into characters (userID, name, race, class) values ('$this->userID', '$charName', '$charRace', '$charClass') ";
    $result=$this->db->query($sql);
    if($this->db->affected_rows == '1')
        {
            return '1';
        }
        else
        {
            return '0';
        }

    //get last insert id     
    $this->charID=$this->db->insert_id;

}
```

Comment: Although unrelated to your problem, I'd highly recommend quoting all variables going into a query using mysqli's [real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php). Currently your code looks susceptible to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: That step is done outside of this class. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving `$this->charID = $this->db->insert_id;` before the if/else, since both will return before getting to the `insert_id` line.

```
function createChar($charName, $charRace, $charClass) {
    //put userId, charName and charRace into database
    $sql = "insert into characters (userID, name, race, class) values ('$this->userID', '$charName', '$charRace', '$charClass') ";
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);

    //get last insert id     
    $this->charID = $this->db->insert_id;

    if($this->db->affected_rows == '1')
    {
        return '1';
    }
    else
    {
        return '0';
    }
}
```

Comment: Moved the line to just before the "return '1'" working correctly now. thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

It can't reach the assigning of the insert_id because of the return statement try to put it on the part before the return happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try below.

quote values properly:

```
  $sql="insert into characters (userID, name, race, class) values 
    ('".$this->userID."', '".$charName."', '".$charRace."','".$charClass."') ";
  $result=$this->db->query($sql);
  $this->charID=$this->db->insert_id;
```

Comment: the insert query is working, it's the insert_id I'm having trouble with

Comment: Try  $this->charID=$this->db->insert_id();

Comment: I tried this. The query was already working, but this made no difference to the insert_id.

Comment: check variable scopes in your class

Comment: I thought about that, but I can access it from outside the class without a problem, but not from inside. at the moment it's declared simply as "var charID;"

Comment: tried to put it on the part before the return happens ? as per @colighto